# Declaring and using MySQL varchar variables

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to do some simple manipulations with variables in MySQL 5.0 but I can't quite get it to work.  I've seen many (very!) different syntaxen for DECLARE/SET, I'm not sure why... in any case I'm presumably confusing them/picking the wrong one/mixing them.

Here's a minimal fragment that fails:

```
DECLARE FOO varchar(7);
DECLARE oldFOO varchar(7);
SET FOO = '138';
SET oldFOO = CONCAT('0', FOO);

update mypermits 
   set person = FOO 
 where person = oldFOO;
```

I've also tried wrapping it with BEGIN... END; and as a PROCEDURE.  In this case MySQL Workbench helpfully tells me: "SQL syntax error near ')'" on the first line and "SQL syntax error near 'DECLARE oldFOO varchar(7)'" on the second.  Otherwise it gives both lines as errors in full, with "SQL syntax error near ..." on both.

Edit: I forgot to mention that I've tried it with and without @s on the variables.  Some resources had it with, others without.

What dumb mistake am I making?

Comment: Post exactly what you are trying to use, because I've created a new procedure and I don't get a syntax error using what you provided -- see my answer.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This works fine for me using MySQL 5.1.35:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `example`.`test` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `example`.`test` ()
BEGIN

  DECLARE FOO varchar(7);
  DECLARE oldFOO varchar(7);
  SET FOO = '138';
  SET oldFOO = CONCAT('0', FOO);

  update mypermits
     set person = FOO
   where person = oldFOO;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `example`.`mypermits`;
CREATE TABLE  `example`.`mypermits` (
  `person` varchar(7) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO mypermits VALUES ('0138');

CALL test()
```

Comment: That seems to work!  The delimiter command is what I needed, apparently.  It's magic to me so far... let me look it up.

Comment: What if i want to declare a string variable that can store maximum value? @OMGPonies

Comment: > "DECLARE is permitted only inside a BEGIN ... END compound statement and must be at its start, before any other statements.". Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/declare.html However, `SET` works nearly everywhere, and `CAST` may be used for explicit types.

Answer (score 12):

I ran into the same problem using MySQL Workbench. According to the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare-local-variable.html), the `DECLARE` "statement declares local variables within stored programs."  That apparently means it is only guaranteed to work with stored procedures/functions.

The solution for me was to simply remove the `DECLARE` statement, and introduce the variable in the `SET` statement.  For your code that would mean:

```
-- DECLARE FOO varchar(7); 
-- DECLARE oldFOO varchar(7);

-- the @ symbol is required
SET @FOO = '138'; 
SET @oldFOO = CONCAT('0', FOO);

UPDATE mypermits SET person = FOO WHERE person = oldFOO;
```

Comment: You will need a `@` symbol to SET variables outside stored procedures/functions. e,g `SET @F00 = '138'`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot the @ in variable declaration. Also I remember having problems with `SET` in MySql a long time ago.

Try

```
DECLARE @FOO varchar(7);
DECLARE @oldFOO varchar(7);
SELECT @FOO = '138';
SELECT @oldFOO = CONCAT('0', @FOO);

update mypermits 
   set person = @FOO 
 where person = @oldFOO;
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the error remains when I put @s on the variables (as I originally had it.)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
declare @foo    varchar(7),
        @oldFoo varchar(7)

set @foo = '138'
set @oldFoo = '0' + @foo
```

Comment: "SQL syntax error near 'declare @foo    varchar(7),
        @oldFoo varchar(7)'"

Comment: I literally just copied and pasted it on a new query and it worked without a problem...do you have any code surrounding this portion?

Comment: No.  I commented out everything else and it still gave that error.

Comment: even with begin and end iam facing this issue !

Answer (score 0):

In Mysql, We can declare and use variables with set command like below

```
mysql> set @foo="manjeet";
mysql> select * from table where name = @foo;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using phpmyadmin to add new routine then don't forget to wrap your code between BEGIN and END[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
Declare @variable type(size);

Set @variable = 'String' or Int ;
```

Example:

```
 Declare @id int;
 set @id = 10;

 Declare @str char(50);
 set @str='Hello' ;
```