# How to retrieve all data from table in MySQL if column value providing null value?

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause, mysql-workbench

I would like to retrieve all data from table in MySQL if column value providing null value?

I have a table like country.
[image]

How to write a query

- If `country = '    '` I need to display all data in table.
- If `country='algeria'`, it will display the particular data.

I need both queries in a single query.

```
i am getting result .but without providing variable  how to write query...
declare @country1 varchar(30)
set @country1 = 'asd'
    SELECT country_id, country
FROM   country
WHERE  ((@country1  = '') or (@country1 != '' and  country.country= @country1));
```

Comment: Neither of those have nothing to do with NULL, and you probably know what to do when you think "I want this OR this to be true..."

Comment: How do you pass the country parameter to the query?

Comment: you can use a case statement for stating your conditions

Comment: variable :nvarchar(30),

Answer (score 0):

If you have an input like `:country`:

```
select 
    country.country_id, country.country 
from 
    country 
where
    country.country = case when TRIM(:country) = '' or :country IS NULL then country.country else :country end
```

---

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE sp1 (x VARCHAR(30))
BEGIN
    SELECT
        country.country_id, country.country 
    FROM 
        country 
    WHERE
        country.country = CASE WHEN TRIM(x) = '' OR x IS NULL THEN country.country ELSE x END;
END;
$$

DELIMITER ;

call sp1('COUNTRY');
```

Comment: i am using MySQL work bench. Declare  $country nvarchar(30)   showing error.

Comment: @Gorigeashokkumar I think [in MySQL Workbench you should create procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3981432/4519059) for that ;).

Answer (score 0):

`null`s are different than empty strings (`''`), and should be checked explicitly with the `is` operator.

Assuming the variable you're passing is `:country`:

```
SELECT country_id, country
FROM   country
WHERE  (:country IS NULL) or (:country = country.country)
```

Comment: i am using MySQL work bench. how to pass :country  variable. when i use declare  it showing error.